# -L and -l commands don't work in Makefile

Tags: c++, c, gcc, makefile

I have following Makefile:

```
TOP = ../Bank/src
CC = gcc

CFLAGS = -g -Wall -std=c99
LDFLAGS = -L$(TOP)
LFLAGS = -lVirtualBank
INCLUDES = -I$(TOP)/VirtualBank/ 
LIBS = VirtualBank.a
 
BANK_SOURCES = $(TOP)/bank.c 
VirtualBank_SOURCES = $(TOP)/VirtualBank/bankServer.c $(TOP)/VirtualBank/dataBase.c $(TOP)/VirtualBank/account.c
 
BANK_OBJECTS = $(BANK_SOURCES:.c=.o)
VirtualBank_OBJECTS = $(VirtualBank_SOURCES:.c=.o)
TARGET = bank

all: VirtualBank.a $(TARGET)
    
VirtualBank.a:$(VirtualBank_OBJECTS)
    rm -f $@
    ar cq $@ $(VirtualBank_OBJECTS)
    mv *.a $(TOP)/

$(VirtualBank_OBJECTS):$(VirtualBank_SOURCES)
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $(VirtualBank_SOURCES)
    mv *.o $(TOP)/VirtualBank/

$(TARGET):$(BANK_OBJECTS) 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $(BANK_OBJECTS) -o $(TARGET) $(LDFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)
    chmod +x $(TARGET)
       
$(BANK_OBJECTS):$(BANK_SOURCES)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(INCLUDES) $(BANK_SOURCES)
    mv *.o $(TOP)/

       
clean: 
    cd ../Bank
    rm -rf *.o bank
    cd $(TOP)
    rm -rf *.o *.a
    cd $(TOP)/VirtualBank
    rm -rf *.o
```

It is from this project: https://github.com/MihaiPro/Bank
When I run `make` command, commpiler doesn't find VirtualBank library. I think the problem is on -l command, I read again about this command, but I don't find what is problem.

Can you help me?

Thanks!

## EDIT

Error message:

```
gcc -g -Wall -std=c99 -I../Bank/src/VirtualBank/  ../Bank/src/bank.o -o bank -L../Bank/src -lVirtualBank
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lVirtualBank
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [bank] Error 1
```

Comment: Do you *have* VirtualBank library? Where?

Comment: What is the command line immediately before the error message?

Comment: it is created when you run makefile. Added last command before error.

Comment: this command: -L$(TOP) say to compiler to look for libs here, right? and -lVirtualBank to use it, right?

Comment: You can see in the `gcc` command line that `-L../Bank/src` is there.  That's what `LDFLAGS` expanded to. The conclusion I reach is that there's no `libVirtualBank.a` (or .so) in `../Bank/src`.  It looks like that's becuase you named it `VirtualBank.a`. I'd suggest using the name `libVirtualBank.a`.

Comment: That makefile is pretty terrible.

Comment: And there absolutely isn't a `libVirtualBank.a` anywhere as the target/file is `VirtualBank.a` as can be seen on the `LIBS` line.

Comment: It might be educational to add `-Wl,--verbose` to the `LDFLAGS` variable.

Comment: @EtanReisner, I know, I'm still beginner in Makefiles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [ld(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ld):

```
-l namespec
--library=namespec
Add the archive or object file specified by namespec to the list of files to link. This option may be used any number of times. If namespec is of the form :filename, ld will search the library path for a file called filename, otherwise it will search the library path for a file called libnamespec.a.
On systems which support shared libraries, ld may also search for files other than libnamespec.a. Specifically, on ELF and SunOS systems, ld will search a directory for a library called libnamespec.so before searching for one called libnamespec.a. (By convention, a ".so" extension indicates a shared library.) Note that this behavior does not apply to :filename, which always specifies a file called filename.

The linker will search an archive only once, at the location where it is specified on the command line. If the archive defines a symbol which was undefined in some object which appeared before the archive on the command line, the linker will include the appropriate file(s) from the archive. However, an undefined symbol in an object appearing later on the command line will not cause the linker to search the archive again.

See the -( option for a way to force the linker to search archives multiple times.

You may list the same archive multiple times on the command line.

This type of archive searching is standard for Unix linkers. However, if you are using ld on AIX , note that it is different from the behaviour of the AIX linker.
```

Your library is called **VirtualBank.a**, but **ld** will look for **libVirtualBank.a**.